# Vuejs (gridsome) - populating head order

Tags: vue.js, gridsome

One of my customer just send me a feedback regarding the order data are generated, and sent to GTM.

He asks me to change the page title BEFORE the url is updated :

[image]

I don't get it because i used vuejs hooks (metaInfo(), mounted()), and i'm not sure whereas is it me who have done something wrong, or is it the default framework behaviour.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? Can you show us some code ?